# Does JVM specifically caches Boolean.(TRUE|FALSE)?

Tags: java, boolean, constants

Given `Boolean` value,

```java
Boolean b = getSome();
```

Is following expression

```java
return Boolean.TRUE == b; // possibly false even b.booleanValue() is true?
```

equal(<del>equivalent</del>) to

```java
return Boolean.TRUE.equal(b);
```

Does the JLS specify regarding any constant preservation of `Boolean.(TRUE|FALSE)`?

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE` *is* a constant. Constants are, err, constant. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: NO, the expression are not the same - just suppose that `getSome()`  ends with `return new Boolean(result);` (deprecated for good reason)  -  `new`  will always create a new instance, unless not completed normally (Exception) - this new instance will not be `== TRUE`

Comment: I feel sorry for myself for forgetting the `new Boolean(boolean)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JLS says that there *may* be caching behavior for values produced by boxing.  However, it does not mandate it.  (It is an implementation detail, as far as the JLS is concerned.)

See [JLS 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

Furthermore, if you create a `Boolean` using `new`, it is guaranteed
that you will get a new object.

See [JLS 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> *"The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. **Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.**"*

So for example:

```
Boolean falze = new Boolean(false);
if (Boolean.FALSE != falze) {
    System.out.println("falze is not FALSE");
}
```

will print the message.

---

> Does the JLS specify regarding any constant preservation of Boolean.(TRUE|FALSE)?

The JLS does not mention those constants.

However, the javadoc for `java.lang.Boolean` does mention that they are constants, and `Boolean` is an immutable type.